# MS Excel Vba Arabic unicode

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, locale, arabic

I have a text file and a macro enabled excel file. the excel file gets (using vba) the string (arabic text) from the text file per line then put it on the sheet1 cells. The problem is the string is not properly displayed. It is displayed in random Japanese characters. (My windows locale is Japan).

Here is my code:

```
Open FilePath For Inputs As #1

Do Until EOF(1)

Line Input #1, textline
ActiveWorkbook.sheets(1).Cell(1,1).Value = textline
 'MsgBox(textline)

Loop

Close#1
```

**Question:** How can I get the string(arabic text) to be still arabic when pasted in the excel file?

Comment: Have you tried setting the cell font to **Arial Unicode MS** after getting the text ??

Comment: Yes I already tried that. If I directly copy paste the Arabic text into Excel its displayed properly.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the VBA code you are using. Also try `MsgBox` the string before output to cell and check if the dialog shows correct content.

Comment: Already tried to display string before output to cell by MsgBox but it is still in different characters. (Not arabic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way around using Ms Excel. Under Data tab > Import Data from text. Dont forget to set the  encoding to UTF-8

Voila! Magic!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after searching in many posts. Please follow the followings

1. Press win key or click on it
2. Type region and click on it when windows finds it
3. Choose administrative tab
4. Under the language for non-Unicode programs you will find "change system locale" key
5. A restart would be required

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, feels like it's been quite a time since the question was raised. 
But still I'd like to propose a solution: 
Using `unicode` `encoding` to represent different language: `Sheet1.Cells(2, 1) = ChrW(&H3091)`, which is standing for character `ゑ`.