# Problem convert the marks from number to rating in Arabic using VBA

Tags: vba, arabic

I tried to convert the marks from number to rating ( i.e  (90 - 100 ) change to (Excellent) , (80 - 89 ) change to (very good))  and so .. The code working fine without any problem , but when i tried to write the rating in Arabic language , the rating appear in the Excel sheet **unknown** as shown below
[image]

I already changed my local system language to Arabic but the same ..

My code as below

```
Private Sub Convert_Click()

Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("a:a"))

For i = 2 To n

 If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & i).Value >= 90 Then
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c" & i).Value = "امتياز"

 Else

 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c" & i).Value = " جيد جدا "
 
 End If
 
Next i

End Sub
```

FYA ,

```
امتياز >> meaning in english  "Excellent"
جيد جدا >> meaning in english "very good"
```

Kind Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246275/ms-excel-vba-arabic-unicode

Comment: Hi @braX .. Thanks for your replay , i already have the marks (i.e numbers ) in the sheet1 and need to convert it to rating and set it in the sheet 2 .. so i don't have any import date from text here

Comment: Just know that it's unicode (UTF-8) as that should give you something to go on... it seems like i've read somewhere that VBA does not support this. Someone with more experience may know differently. i changed your tags to include arabic so that may get someone's attention.

Comment: @braX , Thanks for you .. Hope some one can help me in this ,,

Comment: Again, just knowing that it's UTF-8, you can use that information to look stuff up in google while you wait... i just tried it and here's one of the results - no idea if it helps tho - https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-display-foreign-characters-in-vbe.html

Comment: Do you face the problem only when you try writing from VBA? Are you able to manually input arabic character, as you need?

Comment: @braX , I already did this and the same .. I think i have to use another way around .. in excel i can write in Arabic , so how i can take this value for example found in column (a) raw (1) .. some think like this   (Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c" & i).Value = Application.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("a", 1))  ,, but it not work .. i think i have problem in this code .. can you advice me

Comment: @FaneDuru , yes exactly only when i try writing from VBA , when i insert manual is working fine

Comment: Then, I would suggest you to change the VBA Editor, too: Being in VBE: Tools -> Options -> Font and choose something (Arabic). I can see `Dubay(Arabic`, `San Shereif(Arabic` and so on... Never tested, but you will maybe try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid entering non-ascii characters directly in the vba editor. Even if it works for you (sometimes) due to your locale settings, it won't work for people who are trying to help you.

In this case I would suggest you enter contstant names in excel with values such as:

```
Name       Value
Excellent  "إمتياز"
VeryGood   "جيد جدا"
Good       "جيد"
... and so on
```

[image]
Then change your vba code to something like this

```
Private Sub Convert_Click()

    Dim n As Integer

    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("a:a"))

    For i = 2 To n

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & i).Value >= 90 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c" & i).Value = [Excellent]

        ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & i).Value >= 80
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c" & i).Value = [VeryGood]

        ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & i).Value >= 70
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c" & i).Value = [Good]

        End If
 
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit** (following answer from OP)

Another (similar) approach is to have a dedicated sheet where you define global variables used by the whole application. In this case the code above will still work without change and `[Excellent]` is more readable than `Sheets(Sheet4.Name).Range("A1").Value`. You can alternatively use `"Sheets("Globals").Range("Excellent")`

[image]

**Aside:** Instead `Sheets(Sheet4.Name).Range("A1").Value` you can simply use `Sheet4.Range("A1").Value`

Comment: Many thanks for your support, yes exactly this what i did .. Thanks ..  another question if possible plz , if i using ( i , j ) this mean i :- raw   and  j :-  column .. Also is used (n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("a:a")) ) .... to sure no raw empty .. How i can do this and the loop stop when found column empty

Comment: Note how I changed `Else` to `ElseIf`. This way handles the case where the mark cell is empty as it will not pass any condition.

Comment: Well, I have columns from  (C to  J  ) and unknown of raw number ... My idea to get loop .. check the first column (c) and convert all numbers to rates then after arrive the last raw the counter back  to the column (d) and convert all numbers to rates and after arrive the last raw it go to the column (E)  and so till arrive to column (J) ..

Comment: @ Super Symmetry , Solved .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Super Symmetry for your support .. I used another work around .. I created another sheet and inserted the rating in it with Arabic , then in VBA i called these values.. as example below

```
Private Sub Convert_Click()

Dim n As Integer

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("a:a"))

For i = 2 To n

 If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & i).Value >= 90 Then
 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c" & i).Value = Sheets(Sheet4.Name).Range("A1").Value
  
 Else

 Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c" & i).Value = Sheets(Sheet4.Name).Range("A6").Value
  
 End If
 
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That's how I actually do it in my applications, but I didn't want to confuse things. I updated my answer.